# For DDR4 and DDR5, is tCCD_l timing to be obeyed for accesses in a single row as well?

Tags: computer-architecture, ram, ddr

So I have been trying to learn about DDR4 and DDR5 memories, and it seems that the Column-to-Column delay values (in clock cycles) are different depending on whether consecutive accesses are *inter*-bankgroup, or *intra*-bankgroup. For accesses across different bankgroups, the tCCD_short equals Burst_Length/2, essentially the number of data cycles it takes to transfer data. But for accesses within a bank-group, the tCCD_long can be larger than BL/2.

The common reason I could find on internet, for the larger tCCD within a single bankgroup is that the internal DRAM array is slower than the external bus speed. That makes sense for different rows in a single bank. **However, I could not verify whether the tCCD_l penalty is also to be paid if I am accessing different column elements of the *same* row within the same bank in a bankgroup**. Because, if I have a row open in a bank, the internal DRAM fetch time should be greatly reduced (there is no need for sensing etc., since the data is already in the row buffer). Logically, for an open page buffer, the tCCD value should also equal Burst_Length/2, i.e. tCCD_s. So what's the actual tCCD value in this case?

In essence, can I issue 2 consecutive reads to the same row in the same bank and bankgroup with tCCD_s (since all the data to be read is in the page buffer)?

That, and could anyone here point me to a good book/resource modern DRAM/memory internals (HBM, HMC, DDR5, GDDR6 etc.)?

Answer (score -1):

Same bank, different row is actually one of the worst case scenarios for timing.

Remember that there is only one set of buffers in a bank that can do the actual reading/writing to the DRAM cells.

You have to wait the full time closing the open row and then opening the different row until its ready for data to be read out.

In most other scenarios you can do at least some of these tasks in parallel to the data readout - but not here.

Comment: I mean to ask about the same row in a bank, not different rows. Once a row is open in a bank, the buffers do not have to read/write the DRAM cells, yes?

Comment: Changing bank within a bankgroup causes longer tCCD. That is understandable. But is this also the case for the same bank within a bankgroup?